# Creación de páginas con contenido exclusivamente en php o mixtas?

Tags: php, html

Chicos, no soy nuevo como visitante de StackOverflow, pero sí esta es mi primera cuenta y pregunta. Estoy empezando un proyecto para la creación de una red social en la que ya he desarrollado varios códigos pero de repente me ha saltado una duda importante:

¿Me conviene crear algunas páginas con código HTML predefinidas(-sin contar el index.php- login.php, registro.php, perfil.php, etc) o es mejor crear solo el índex y que, según la navegación del usuário, el php genere los formularios y elementos HTML de las nuevas páginas que serán visitadas? La pregunta va más enfocada a una respuesta relacionada a la velocidad de carga de las páginas y de navegación del própio usuario, teniendo en cuenta que se trabajará mucho con imagenes, videos y(talvez) contenido externo.

Entiendo que usando demasiado el php puedo someterme a riegos de error tras error, pero, con un código limpio y testeado, ¿conseguiría un desempeño más aprimorado si el sitio comenzara con menos código pronto en HTML?

Desde ya gracias por la atención y me disculpo si estoy preguntando algo demasiado obvio y, si lo es, al menos me saco un peso de encima.

> Edición: Bueno, para ser un poco más exacto, pongamos el siguiente ejemplo:

El index tiene el siguiente formato:

```
<?php

    include header.php; /*que contendría evidentemente todo el inicio del 
    html +tags "link" y "script"*/

    include login.php;
    include registro.php;

    include footer.php;
?>
```

Un documento llamado, por ejemplo, verifica.php procesaría los datos y generaría una página de perfil solamente SI el Login/registro o cualquier requisición es efectuada exitosamente:

```
<?php
    include "connection.php";

?>
<?php

$email = $_POST['user-mail'];
$pass = $_POST['user-pass'];

if($conn){


    //Perform queries 
    mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM $dbName"); //obviamente el nombre del banco no es una variable en el contexto original
    $verifyExists = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE mail LIKE 
    '$email' AND pass LIKE '$pass'");
    mysqli_num_rows($verifyExists);

if(mysqli_num_rows($verifyExists)){
    while($userData = mysqli_fetch_array($verifyExists)){
    $userName = $userData['name'];
    $userAlias = $userData['alias'];
    $userMail = $userData['mail'];
    $userPass = $userData['pass'];
    echo "Login Successful! Welcome:".$userName;
    echo "<br>Your email:".$userMail;
    echo "<br>Your alias:".$userAlias;
/*los "echo" serían relenados con el contenido de la página de
 perfil propiamente dicha, que sería llamada en el index.php solamente si 
 estas requisiciones se cumplen. Si no, en la carpeta del sitio, no se 
 genera ninguna página llamada "perfil.php", por ejemplo.*/
    }


    }else{
    echo "Sorry, email or password incorrect.";
    }

}
?>
```

En base a este código, mi pregunta sería si genero los elementos para crear una página de perfil de usuário SOLAMENTE si los datos/conexión con el banco/requisiciones se procesan correctamente(por tanto, los genero via php), o genero una página de perfil estática que se alimente de esos datos cada vez que un usuário use el sitio web? Cual de las dos opciones es más rápida y fiable?

Comment: No se si entendi bien, la consulta es si hacer todo en una sola pagina (me imagino con intervencion de AJAX) o si vas enlazando a otras paginas PHP?

Comment: Todo tu criterio. Aun que php recibe más y más esteroide, sigue siendo un script que se puede integrar en paginas html como te conviene.Puede ser muy performante incluso de limitarse a generar solo lo necesario con php y dejar todo estatico a html y css.

Comment: Hola, si la página es  estática, solo tienes que usar contenido **html**, **CSS**, **javascrpt**. En caso contrario de que la página sea dinámica, se usarías el php para la interacción de las bd y se combinarias con todo lo anterior. Lo que si no es recomendable  es que cargues el contenido **html** desde php ya que eso si disminulle el rendimiento  del php, lo recomendado es intercalarlo  o hacer  el vínculo con ajax.

Answer (score 0):

A manera de explicación dejame decirte que **PHP** (Hypertext Preprocessor)es un lenguaje de programación para paginas web dinámicas, **HTML** es un lenguaje de marcado, **CSS** es un lenguaje de estilo y Javascript es un lenguaje de comportamiento (también dinámico).

Existen Frameworks de cada lenguaje(bootstrap,Foundation,laravel,cakephp,jquery,react,etc), no esta mal que preguntes porque es la unica manera de aprender sobretodo en el mundo de la desarrollo web y la seguridad informática, pero si investigas un poco, en el Google, sabrás que cada lenguaje es complemento de el otro, no es una opción es una necesidad, hoy en día casi todos los sitios web llevan todos los lenguajes que te he mencionado.  Ahora bien existen especialistas en cada lenguaje y la comunidad les pone nombre (backend, frontend, maketador web, diseñador web, etc), pero al final dependiendo de lo que hagas al final del dia siempre necesitaras de los otros lenguajes para hacer un desarrollo web útil.

Como dato adicional, el Desarrollador(Developer) que maneja todos los lenguajes web, incluyendo servidores (windows-linux) y su seguridad informática, se le llama Fullstack Developer Web. Espero te sirva mi comentario, en tu duda sobre programación mixta, como tu le llamaste.